# Will this function only be called once?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, constants

Here is the relevant part of my program

```
// constants.h
extern const std::map<std::string, int> constMap;

// constants.cpp
std::map<std::string, int> initConstMap()
{
    //stuff required to initialize constMap
} 
const std::map<std::string, int> constMap = initConstMap();

\\ main.cpp
...
for (int i = 0, n = LOTS_OF TIMES; i < n; ++i){
    doSomethingWith(constMap[i]);
}
...
```

I wonder if, whenever I use the constMap variable during my main program, will it run the "initConstMap" function each time, or not?  The const map obviously is constant and so it does not need initialized many times. (*note the main cpp is a manufactured example, its not really what my program is doing.  I'm just simplifying things for the sake of the question).

Comment: You can add a `static` global variable and count how many times it's called.

Comment: Or you can actually set a breakpoint and debug your program

Comment: why not use a meyers' singleton, that's the common idiom and very much simpler and safer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf  think Meyer's singleton is a static variable in a function, guaranteed to be initialized exactly once at first use, in a thread-safe manner. Now you say that would be simpler and safer. I cannot see how that would be simpler, so I must assume it's safer. Is this const variable initialization not thread-safe?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: the meyers' singleton is decidedly simpler and shorter code. since it avoids the static initialization order fiasco it's also safer. the fiasco is discussed in the c++ faq.

Comment: Upvoded for `n = LOTS_OF TIMES`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will be called only one time, if you're asking about this specific code snippet - actually it couldn't be called more times, since it's `const`, and `const` forbids redefining a variable. What you could do however, is change your structures to be `constexpr`, so everything is done at compilation time - that's what you're after.

Comment: `constexpr` cannot be done with allocation required for `std::map`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only call it once, then the function will be called only once. And when called for initializing a global variable it will be called before `main` as well.

Be careful through, so you don't experience [the static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comments, you can actually count how many times the initConstMap function is called, but looking at your code, it is called only once.

Please note, this means once every time the relevant part of constants.cpp is called, so depending on the rest of your program, it might be called more often. For sure, it is not called from the for loop.